# JSON.parse(). Accessing data and using it to populate dom

Tags: javascript, json

JSON.parse Syntax: JSON.parse(text[, reviver]) Parameters: text-The string to parse as JSON. reviver- Optional If a function, this prescribes how the value originally produced by parsing is transformed, before being returned. Return value The Object corresponding to the given JSON text.

I really don't understand this. I have a JSON file that I need to use the data within to populate the DOM but I don't understand JSON.parse. When I tried to use this I used

```
var myData = JSON.parse({ "site": { "id": "example", "name": "example1" }...etc});
```

then tried to access it using dot notation.

```
console.log(myData.site.id);
```

I don't know what I'm doing, I've now figured out 200+ ways not to do it

Comment: What you do wrong is this: JSON is a *string*. Never anything else. You are not passing a string to `JSON.parse()` in your sample.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse` expects a JSON string as its parameter, but you are passing javascript object literal, which is an object already and does not need parsing.

Depending on your use case you can either add quotes to make the parameter string:

```
var myData = JSON.parse('{ "site": { "id": "example", "name": "example1" }}');
```

Or don't use `JSON.parse` at all and you can work with your object directly.

```
var myData = { "site": { "id": "example", "name": "example1" }};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass JSON string to JSON.parse(yourJSONString) Then you can get values by call headers as follows.

```
var myRst = JSON.parse('{ "site": { "id": "example", "name": "example1" }}')
```

Then

```
myRst.site.id
```

```js
    var myRst = JSON.parse('{ "site": { "id": "example", "name": "example1" }}')
    
    console.log(myRst.site.id)
```